# Cocoa fullscreen window on secondary display

Tags: cocoa, fullscreen, nswindow

I have the follow code which mostly works apart from I can never see the `myWindow` that I create. If I do `[myWindow isVisible]` it returns `1`. The `CGDisplayCapture` works fine as it blanks out the screen. I've checked all the variables I pass into the NSWindow init method.

Am I missing something really obvious? Here's the code:

```
// Find the screen we want
NSScreen *screen                = [[NSScreen screens] objectAtIndex:1];
NSNumber *displayID             = [[screen deviceDescription] 
                                  objectForKey:@"NSScreenNumber"];
CGDirectDisplayID CGDisplayID   = (CGDirectDisplayID) [displayID intValue];

// Capture the secondary display
if (CGDisplayCapture( CGDisplayID ) != kCGErrorSuccess) {
  NSLog( @"Couldn't capture the secondary display" );
}

// Draw a new window to fill the screen
NSRect screenRect = [screen frame];
NSWindow *myWindow = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:screenRect
                                               styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask
                                                 backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
                                                   defer:NO
                                                  screen:screen];

// Set the level of the new window and other settings
NSInteger windowLevel = CGShieldingWindowLevel();
[myWindow setLevel: windowLevel];
[myWindow setBackgroundColor:[NSColor blueColor]];
[myWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
```

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

If you can require 10.5 or above, **please** use NSView's [-enterFullScreenMode:withOptions:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000014-SW5) and the matching -exitFullScreenModeWithOptions:. This properly shifts the responsibility to a container view (which can still have its own complex set of subviews) and frees you from some of the gotcha's of manually messing with window levels, etc.

Answer (score 1):

What does this window look like if you don't make it full-screen?

I don't see you adding any views to the window you're creating.  If your window's content view is an NSView instance, it's not going to do any drawing.

Comment: If I just run `[[NSWindow alloc] init];` then I get a little blue window appear. So maybe it's something in that method but `screenRect` and `screen` are ok since I've check them by using `NSLog`.

Comment: It's been a long time since I needed to make a window full-screen in the way that you're doing.  Is there some reason why you're not just sending -enterFullScreenMode:withOptions: to a view that contains whatever you're trying to draw?

Comment: Don't think so but surely you need to create a window anyway to contain a view, you can't make a view fullscreen without a window surely? I passed `[NSScreen mainScreen]` into the screen parameter and that worked so I need to figure out why it doesn't like the `NSScreen` i'm sending it as using mainScreen isn't that reliable when I want the secondary display. If that doesn't work I'll try the view solution. Thanks for you help.